# tkinter gui stops responding while 2 other threads open

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, pyhook

```
from pythoncom import PumpWaitingMessages 
import pyHook, threading 
import tkinter as tk

threadsRun = 1 
token = 0

def pas():
  while threadsRun:
    pass

def listen(startButton): 
    """Listens for keystrokes"""

    def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
        """A key was pressed"""
        global threadsRun
        if event.Key == "R":
            startButton.config(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.NORMAL, text="Start")
            threadsRun = 0
        return True

    hm = pyHook.HookManager()
    hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
    hm.HookKeyboard()
    while threadsRun:
        PumpWaitingMessages()
    else:
        hm.UnhookKeyboard()

def simplegui():

    def threadmaker():
        """Starts threads running listen() and pas()"""
        startButton.config(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED, text="r=stop listening")
        global token, threadsRun
        threadsRun = 1
        token += 1
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=pas, name='pas{}'.format(token))
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=listen, args=(startButton,), name='listen{}'.format(token))
        t1.start()
        t2.start()

    def destroy():
        """exit program"""
        global threadsRun
        threadsRun = 0
        root.destroy()

    startButton = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=threadmaker, height=10, width=20)
    startButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

    quitButton = tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=destroy, height=10, width=20)
    quitButton.grid(row=1, column=1)

root = tk.Tk() 
simplegui() 
root.mainloop()
```

Code description: 
`simplegui()` creates two threads to run 
`pas()` and 
`listen()` 
simultaneously.

`listen()` waits for keyboard presses(only `r` does anything: exits both threads/functions). 
`pas()` does nothing but is needed to reproduce bug.

Problem description: 
After clicking start, pressing any button on the keyboard can cause `tkinter` to stop responding. 
~2/3rd of the time `r` will behave as intended. 
I'm using Spyder IDE (python 3.5).

Some observations:  
Using print statements, the program will go into `while threadsRun` loop, in `listen()`, before the crash, but didn't reach `OnKeyboardEvent()` *print* statement.  
Can wait a long time before pressing a key and it may freeze.  
Can press a key instantly after pressing start and it may function as intended.  
Removing `t1 = ...` and `t1.start()` lines allows program to run bug free.
Alternatively, removing all `tkinter` code allows program to run bug free.
Mashing a bunch of keys all at once freezes it.
If I place a print statement inside the `while threadsRun` loop, `r` will rarely work.

I've read in other posts, `tkinter` is not thread safe, and to use a queue. But I don't understand how. I also think maybe something else is wrong because it works sometimes. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1v5v3r/tkinter_uis_toplevel_freezes_on_windows_machine/

Thanks very much for reading.

Comment: Thanks for edit and answer R4PH43L.  I wasn't able to implement class and queue but it did motivate me to learn classes which is good :).  I found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101906/combining-tkinter-mainloop-with-another-event-listener?rq=1  I was able to reconstruct the code without `pumpwaitingmessages()`, So it may have been having two messagepumps(I'm assuming there is one in `mainloop()`), that caused the lockup. My new code works as intended now.

Answer (score 0):

One attempt I managed to use for threads and queues is the following (replaced used code with multiple pseudo-code entries)

The Class works as a session watchdog and uses sql commands gather logged in users, then uses threads for their location detection (geoip)

#### class SessionWatchdog

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import Queue

import Locator

class SessionWatchdog(ttk.Frame):
    """
    Class to monitor active Sessions including Location in a threaded environment
    """
    __queue = None 
    __sql = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #...
        # Create the Queue
        self.__queue = Queue.Queue()

    def inqueue(self):
        """ Handle Input from watchdog worker Thread """

        if self.__queue.empty():
            return

        while self.__queue.qsize():
            """
                Use 
                try:
                    self.__queue.get()
                finally:
                    self.__queue.task_done()

                to retrieve data from the queue
            """
            pass

    def gather_data(self, queue):
        """
        Retrieve online users and locate them
        """
        if self.__sql:
            threads = []

            # gather data via sql
            # ....
            # ....
            for data in sql_result:
                thread = Locator(queue, data)
                threads.append(thread)
                thread.start()

            for thread in threads:
                thread.join()
```

Locator to fill the queue:

#### class Locator

```
import threading
import Queue

class Locator(threading.Thread):
    """
    docstring
    """

    __base_url = "http://freegeoip.net/json/{}"

    def __init__(self, queue, user_information):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.queue = queue
        self.user_information = user_information
    def run(self):
        """ add location information to data (self.user_information)
            to improve performance, we put the localization in single threads.
        """
        located_user = []
        # locate the user in a function, NOT method!
        self.queue.put(located_user, False)
```